# Get sales total and GROUP BY DAY with Sale price x Amount -Discount

Tags: mysql

I'm trying get a total of sales by day teaking into count the amount of item sold and if any discount apply. This is what I have.

| item_sale_price | item_sale_qty | discount_percentage | sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 250000 | 5 | 10 | 2021-06-01 |
| 100000 | 1 | 0 | 2021-06-02 |
| 25000 | 2 | 5 | 2021-06-02 |

```
SELECT item_sale_price * item_sale_qty - (item_sale_price * item_sale_qty - (discount_percentage / 100)) AS total_per_day 
FROM sales_items where sale_date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' GROUP BY DAY(sale_date)";
```

Comment: and where is the problem? Also your code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** so swithc to **prepared statements with parameters** see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must multiply `item_sale_price` by `1 - discount_percentage / 100` to get the price after discount.
Also you should use `SUM()` aggregate function to get the total:

```
SELECT SUM(item_sale_qty * item_sale_price * (1 - discount_percentage / 100)) AS total_per_day 
FROM sales_items 
WHERE sale_date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' 
GROUP BY DAY(sale_date);
```

I'm not sure why you group by `DAY(sale_date)` and not just `sale_date`.

This makes more sense:

```
SELECT sale_date,
       SUM(item_sale_qty * item_sale_price * (1 - discount_percentage / 100)) AS total_per_day 
FROM sales_items 
WHERE sale_date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' 
GROUP BY sale_date;
```

Comment: You are right @forpas there is no need of having DAY(). I thank you for your help :-).